# Laravel on form submit reload page with message and same time open a new tab with data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

In laravel when a form data store in database i need reload that form with successful message and at the same time open a new tab with saved data. So how to i do this. here is my store method controller code :

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($request) {
            $lastid = DB::table('invmaster')->pluck('id')->last()+1;
            $invdate =now()->format('ym');
            $invformate = str_pad($invdate, 9, "0", STR_PAD_RIGHT);
            $invoice_no = "DI".($invformate+$lastid);
            $invoiceMaster = InvMaster::create([
                'InvDate' => request()->input('InvDate'),
                'InvNo' => $invoice_no,
                'PatientName' => request()->input('PatientName'),
                'AdvanceAmt' => request()->input('AdvanceAmt'),
            ]);
        });
        Session::flash('message','Added  Successfully');
        return redirect('/diagnosis-invoices/create');
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure with your expect. But do u want to display message after create success?

Comment: You are talking about frontend issues, while you're code is showing backend. You need to solve showing message and opening tab in frontend. In backend, you may just return simple JSON with the saved data, which your front-end can show, instead of returning a redirect

Comment: is there any way to solve this issue in backend?

Comment: You could redirect with flashing the added data, and display that data in your view. And in your view add JavaScript code to open an extra window. Still, most of this work is frontend. Backend can not do things like open tabs.